# Sorting a collection of objects in an Angular pipe by the first value of sub-sub-nested array

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, pipe

Note:

- I'm an amateur dev with still a lot to learn.
- I don't think this is a duplicate : some other questions are related (and I tried to adapt the suggested solutions) but without success. Having to use it inside an Angular pipe makes it also more difficult since the properties of the movies are read-only.

The collection is made of movies:

```
interface Movie {
  title: string;
  schedules: [
    {
      theater: string,
      start:   Date[]  // array of dates such as "2017-06-18T17:20:00.000+02:00"
                       // already sorted in ascending order
    }
  ]
}
```

The user can filter by starting time, so I've set up two consecutives pipes:

```
<div *ngFor="movies | moviesFilter:filter_parameters | moviesSort">
...
```

The filter pipe works fine, but I just spent the last 3 hours (!) trying to code the sort pipe.

**I'd like to sort the filtered collection by the earliest starting time**, e.g. by schedules[0].start[0]

```
Pipe({
  name: 'moviesSort',
  pure: true
})
export class MoviesSortPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(movies:movie[]):movie[] {
     ...
     ...
     return sorted_movies;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation is to move away from pipes for sorting. Do the sorting in your regular business logic.

The Angular team explains here:
https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists.
>   Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy.
>   There are no equivalents in Angular.
>
> This isn't an oversight. Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they
>   perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification.